# ExtJS - 'combocolumn' based renderer - rowediting does not register event or do what it is supposed to

Tags: extjs

http://2gears.com/2011/05/combobox-editor-remote-and-renderer-for-extjs-editorgridpanel/comment-page-2/#comment-11050?

Please see the function.

I am not using the 'combocolumn' completely. However i have used the major components. Please advise if there is a possibility it should work. As of now the grid refuses to render the column itself and I am unable to pinpoint what the bug is as the code is simply the same?
I did this not to act smart :) - but to simplify and run it on 1 column before standardizing the component common to the project.

**The COMBO RENDERING fn()**

```
<code>
function ComboBoxRenderer(combo, gridId) {

    var getValue = function (value) {
        var idx = combo.store.find(combo.valueField, value);
        var rec = combo.store.getAt(idx);
        if (rec) {
            return rec.get(combo.displayField);
        }
        return value;
    };

    return function (value) {
        if (combo.store.getCount() === 0 && gridId) {
            console.log(combo.store.getCount()+gridId);
            combo.store.on(
                    'load',
                    function () {
                        var grid = Ext.getCmp(gridId);
                        if (grid) {
                            grid.getView().refresh();
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        single: true
                    }
            );
            return value;
        }

        return getValue(value);
    };
//    Ext.getCmp(gridId).getView().refresh();
}
</code>
```

**Editor - in Grid Column Model**

{
            header: 'Plan Type',
            dataIndex: 'plan_id',
    editor: {
    //            allowBlank: 'false',
                xtype: 'combobox',
                queryMode: 'local',
                store: planTypeStore,
                displayField: 'plan_name',
                valueField: 'plan_id'
                }
                ,renderer: ComboBoxRenderer(this.editor, 'gridPanelId')
    /*this is the docs based renderrer - which wont work */
    //, renderer: function (val) {
    //                var rec = planTypeStore.findRecord('plan_id', val);
    //                return (rec !== null ? rec.get("plan_name") : '');
    //            }

Comment: The content in the Grid panel column - is now with the entire function and when rowediting is fired it shows the combox editor and return after updating to listing the entire function text  in the column

Comment: What is `this.editor`? Is that defined somewhere else or is it supposed to be a reference to the editor defined above the renderer?

Comment: renderer: ComboBoxRenderer(this.editor, 'gripPanelId'); kindly consider as stated , yes thats the columns editor for rowediting plugin

Comment: It looks suspicious to me. I would have expected `this.editor = new Ext.ComboBox({...});` then in the model: `editor: this.editor`